# Two identical namespaces with dirfferent prefixes in XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

So, I try creating Xml document with next code:

```
XNamespace spr1 = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
XNamespace ex = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel";
XNamespace spr2 = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
XNamespace rec = "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40";

var xworkbook = new XElement(spr1 + "Workbook");

xworkbook.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "x", ex));
xworkbook.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns +"ss", spr2));
xworkbook.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "html", rec));
```

This code make next xml:

```
<ss:Workbook xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <!--Xml body-->
</ss:Workbook>
```

But I expect this:

```
 <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 </Workbook>
```

How to build Workbook element without "ss" prefix and with needed "xmlns" attribute?

Comment: Why? What problems do you have with the current format?

Comment: Bear in mind - the prefixes only have any meaning within the local context of your XML document. `<a xmlns="urn:def"/>` and `<c:a xmlns:c="urn:def"/>` are exactly the same thing, from a logical perspective. They're both describing an `a` element in the `urn:def` namespace.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Even though they should be exactly the same thing, I have some recollection of MS Office being very particular about how elements are named and how their namespaces are declared, and OP may be running into issues like that.

Comment: It seems that `XDocument` may not have a way of representing what you're trying to create. Even if I use `XElement.Parse()` on that second bit of XML, it still changes the element's namespace prefix to `ss:`. The old-style `XmlDocument` API does not have this issue. Perhaps you could use that?

Comment: @JLRishe XDocument more useful api than XmlDocument by my opinion

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Does it mean that I need insert "ss" prefix before every element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ to XML uses the namespace prefix that is closest as it looks through all the attributes in reverse order from the current element to the root. So if you add the default namespace explicitly at the end, then `Workbook` will use that and not the `ss` prefix.

```
XNamespace ss = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
XNamespace ex = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel";
XNamespace html = "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40";

var workbook = new XElement(
    ss + "Workbook",
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "x", ex),
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ss", ss),
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "html", html),
    new XAttribute("xmlns", ss)
);
```

This gives you the XML below:

```
<Workbook xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
          xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"              
          xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" 
          xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" />
```

As stated in the comments, the two documents in your question are semantically the same. Any XML parser shouldn't care about the difference between the two documents.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
                "<Workbook xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\"" +
                     " xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\"" +
                     " xmlns:ss=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\"" +
                     " xmlns:html=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\">" +
                "</Workbook>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement workbook = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;
            XNamespace ssNs = workbook.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("ss");

            XElement worksheet = new XElement(ssNs + "Worksheet");
            workbook.Add(worksheet);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for reply, but it is workaround. I will check your answer if I will not found another solution.

Comment: Not sure why you consider this a work-around since it works.  The namespaces in Net is buggy and I find it is much easier to just parse the namespaces than to attempt to get the Net Library to work properly.  Besides my code is much easier to understand.  With Net library you should always make the default namespace the last attribute.